# Why does Microsoft Security Essentials ask for a scan everytime I log on?

Tags: windows, ms-security-essentials

I have used MSE for some time now with great success.

All of a sudden, starting 3 months ago or so, MSE calls for a scan every time I log on.  It never used to do that and I am wondering why it does now.  I have two computers both running Windows 7 ultimate.  Both have the same problem.

Comment: It could be one of the updates, but then I would expect others to be complaining about the same issue. Did you change anything in the options? I believe there is a setting to specify when it runs. Check to see if it has been changed. Also, is there a specific dialog that prompts you to do a scan? If so, consider posting a screenshot of it.

Comment: Every time you log on, or every day you log on?

Comment: How often do you log on? At least once a day? Once a week?

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem crop up a few days ago. Later learnt the culprit was CCleaner, which cleaned out the scan logs.